# LaTeX \usepackage{datetime} and \usepackage{scrtime} are off by an hour

Tags: datetime, sharelatex

I want to print the current time in my LaTeX file but both `\usepackage{datetime}`
and `\usepackage{scrtime}` show the wrong time. Can I correct to a different time zone? Adjust for daylight savings?

I am writing in `https://www.sharelatex.com/` so I suppose it is the server time that is being shown.

Comment: I don't think there's much to do on the TeX side, without knowing the time zone the server belongs to. And it would be much easier if *they* provided a user's preference for setting their own time zone: TeX asks the OS for time and date.

Comment: What about a new command which simply prints out the time minus one hour? I'm lacking of the skills to write such a command, but if you adapt your question, you'l probably get your answer.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Answer (score 6):

You can access the time zone via `\pdfcreationdate`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\def\parsepdfdatetime#1:#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9{%
  \def\theyear{#2#3#4#5}%
  \def\themonth{#6#7}%
  \def\theday{#8#9}%
  \parsepdftime
}

\def\parsepdftime#1#2#3#4#5#6#7\endparsepdfdatetime{%
  \def\thehour{#1#2}%
  \def\theminute{#3#4}%
  \def\thesecond{#5#6}%
  \ifstrequal{#7}{Z}
  {%
    \def\thetimezonehour{+00}%
    \def\thetimezoneminute{00}%
  }%
  {%
    \parsepdftimezone#7%
  }%
}

\def\parsepdftimezone#1'#2'{%
  \def\thetimezonehour{#1}%
  \def\thetimezoneminute{#2}%
}

\newcommand*{\thetimezone}{\thetimezonehour:\thetimezoneminute}

\begin{document}

\expandafter\parsepdfdatetime\pdfcreationdate\endparsepdfdatetime

This document was created on: 
\theyear-\themonth-\theday\ \thehour:\theminute:\thesecond\ \thetimezone.

\end{document}
```

For me, this displays:

[image: This document was created on: 2014-03-26 15:35:16 +00:00]

**Edit:**

With this information, it's now possible to convert to another time zone. The example below converts to Zulu time (+00:00):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgfkeys,pgfcalendar}

\def\parsepdfdatetime#1:#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9{%
  \def\theyear{#2#3#4#5}%
  \def\themonth{#6#7}%
  \def\theday{#8#9}%
  \parsepdftime
}

\def\parsepdftime#1#2#3#4#5#6#7\endparsepdfdatetime{%
  \def\thehour{#1#2}%
  \def\theminute{#3#4}%
  \def\thesecond{#5#6}%
  \ifstrequal{#7}{Z}
  {%
    \def\thetimezonehour{+00}%
    \def\thetimezoneminute{00}%
  }%
  {%
    \parsepdftimezone#7%
  }%
}

\def\parsepdftimezone#1'#2'{%
  \def\thetimezonehour{#1}%
  \def\thetimezoneminute{#2}%
}

\newcommand*{\thetimezone}{\thetimezonehour:\thetimezoneminute}

\newcount\julianday
\newcount\dayofweek

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\setzulutime}{%
  \pgfcalendardatetojulian{\theyear-\themonth-\theday}{\julianday}%
%(\count@ is a temporary scratch count register)
% First adjust the minute offset if non-zero
  \ifnum\thetimezoneminute=0\relax
  \else
    \count@=\theminute\relax
% Add or subtract the offset minute
    \ifnum\thetimezonehour<0\relax
      \advance\count@ by -\thetimezoneminute\relax
    \else
      \advance\count@ by \thetimezoneminute\relax
    \fi
    \edef\theminute{\number\count@}%
% Does the hour need adjusting?
    \ifnum\count@<0\relax
      \advance\count@ by 60\relax
      \edef\theminute{\number\count@}%
% Need to subtract 1 from the hour
% but does the day need adjusting?
      \ifnum\thehour=0\relax
       \def\thehour{23}%
% Day needs adjusting.
       \advance\julianday by -1\relax
      \else
% Subtract 1 from the hour
        \count@ = \thehour\relax
        \advance\count@ by -1\relax
        \edef\thehour{\number\count@}%
      \fi
    \else
% Minute isn't negative. Is it >= 60?
      \ifnum\count@>59\relax
        \advance\count@ by -60\relax
        \edef\theminute{\number\count@}%
% Add 1 to the hour
        \count@ = \thehour\relax
        \advance\count@ by 1\relax
        \edef\thehour{\number\count@}%
% Does the day need adjusting?
        \ifnum\thehour=24\relax
          \def\thehour{00}%
          \advance\julianday by 1\relax
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
% Now adjust the hour offset if non-zero
  \ifnum\thetimezonehour=0\relax
  \else
    \count@=\thehour\relax
    \advance\count@ by \thetimezonehour\relax
% Does the day need adjusting?
    \ifnum\count@<0\relax
      \advance\count@ by 24\relax
      \edef\thehour{\number\count@}%
      \advance\julianday by -1\relax
    \else
      \ifnum\count@>23\relax
      \advance\count@ by -24\relax
      \edef\thehour{\number\count@}%
      \advance\julianday by 1\relax
      \else
        \edef\thehour{\number\count@}%
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
  \pgfcalendarjuliantodate{\julianday}{\theyear}{\themonth}{\theday}%
  \pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday{\julianday}{\dayofweek}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\parsepdfdatetime D:20130408144644+01'00'\endparsepdfdatetime

This document was created on: 
\theyear-\themonth-\theday\ \thehour:\theminute:\thesecond\ \thetimezone.

\setzulutime
UTC+00:00 time stamp:
\theyear-\themonth-\theday\ \thehour:\theminute:\thesecond.

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of result]

Comment: This is nice, but it doesn't solve the problem; it just tells what time zone the server of ShareLaTeX.com belongs to.

Comment: @egreg But with that information, it's possible to convert to local time. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

As, in fact, only the hour needs to be adjusted to your timezone, you can also just increase/decrease the *\currenthour* register, provided by the *datetime* package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nodayofweek]{datetime}

\begin{document}

% Format output
\ddmmyyyydate

% Un-adjusted
[Compiled \today, \currenttime] 
\par

% advance the hour register by nr of hours
% negative values if you want to subtract
\advance\currenthour by 2

%Adjusted output
[Compiled \today, \the\currenthour:\the\currentminute]

\end{document}
```

This will result in the following:

[image]

**Note** that this workaround, needs manual checking. If, for example, the sharelatex.com server that you're compiling on happens to be in a different timezone, your output changes accordingly.

**EDIT**: I just realized, that the date also has to be considered, when you're adjusting the time around the change of day, e.g. the time on the server is 23:30 and you want to advance by two hours...

**Consider this as a quick-fix only.**

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Thanks and thanks also for the huge amount of contributions you've made to the LaTeX community.