# Offset section currenttime by hours

Tags: datetime, datetime2, advdate

I want to change timezone in a section of a document. An hour offset from server time would suffice. Using package datetime, how do I add or subtract hours from date \today?

Using advdate and datetime I am  only successful in adding or subtracting integer days from \today.

```
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{advdate}
\daymonthyear{\AdvanceDate[-1]\today \space \currenttime}
```

which outputs the UTC date and time from exactly 1 day earlier.

Comment: welcome -- have alook at the answer below and please accept if it meets the requirement -- taken from --  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167751/latex-usepackagedatetime-and-usepackagescrtime-are-off-by-an-hour

Comment: Do you want to keep using `datetime`, or is the `datetime2` package also acceptable? That would make it easier, because `datetime2` has commands to set the time zone explicitly.

Comment: datetime2 sounds great!

Answer (score 1):

The question did not really make clear what the expected input and output is, however here is a guess using the `datetime2` package.

This package defines a command to convert a given time to Zulu time, which is UTC+00:00 (also known as GMT). This command accepts the time zone as an argument. When you print such a date then the displayed date is converted to the time zone of the system that you use to compile the document. Therefore you can use this to add or subtract hours from the displayed date by providing different time zones as argument. The conversion also takes the date into account.

In the MWE below I defined a helper command `\modifytz` with three arguments: the original datetime object (obtained with `\DTMsavenow` or `\DTMsavetimestamp`), the new datetime object, and the time zone offset. The original and new datetime objects can be the same, in that case the original gets overwritten. The helper command extracts the values for year, month etc. from the datetime object to use as arguments for `\DTMsaveaszulutime`.

Note that a positive offset moves the time back and a negative offset moves the time forward. My own time zone is UTC+01:00, if you are in a negative time zone then it is probably the other way around.

The code demonstrates the use with the current time (similar to `\today`) and with a manually entered time, to show the date shift.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showzone=false]{datetime2}
\usepackage{datetime2-calc}

\newcommand{\modifytz}[3]{%
\DTMsaveaszulutime{#2}{\DTMfetchyear{#1}}{\DTMfetchmonth{#1}}{\DTMfetchday{#1}}{\DTMfetchhour{#1}}{\DTMfetchminute{#1}}{\DTMfetchsecond{#1}}{#3}{00}%
}
\begin{document}


\DTMsavenow{now}
[Compiled \DTMuse{now}]

\modifytz{now}{newtime}{1}
[Compiled \DTMuse{newtime}]

\modifytz{now}{now}{-3}
[Compiled \DTMuse{now}]

\DTMsavetimestamp{latenight}{2021-04-07T23:15:00Z}
Late night: \DTMuse{latenight}

\modifytz{latenight}{diffday}{-2}
Different day: \DTMuse{diffday}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nodayofweek]{datetime}

\begin{document}
    
    % Format output
    \ddmmyyyydate
    
    % Un-adjusted
    [Compiled \today, \currenttime] 
    \par
    
    % advance the hour register by nr of hours
    % negative values if you want to subtract
    \advance\currenthour by 2
    
    %Adjusted output
    [Compiled \today, \the\currenthour:\the\currentminute]
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't consider the date. If you add 24 to the second instance of \currenthour it will say 33:10.

Comment: `An hour offset from server time would suffice.`   -- this is what the question states